# Bootstrapping Standard Error of parameter for a Poisson distribution?

Tags: poisson-distribution, bootstrap

Let's say I have observed a Poisson Process for a total amount of time $T$. I can estimate the rate per unit time $r$ of the distribution by dividing the number of observed occurrences $k$ by $T$. I know there is a formula for computing the standard error of this parameter, but I'm interested in the bootstrapping procedure under these conditions?

Specifically, I am curious because I don't have discrete samples to sample across. I can think of at least two ways to bootstrap here:

1. I can chunk up $T$ to equally sized chunks, then compute bootstrap using these chunks
2. I can uniformly sample windows of time of a fixed size to construct my estimate.

What is the correct way of bootstrapping under these conditions?

Comment: Do you know when the events occurred? If not, how do (1) or (2) work?

Comment: @Henry yes I know when the events occurred. I have a recorded stream of events.

Comment: There are many kinds of bootstrap. You could use a form of parametric bootstrap for example. If you have the intetevent times, one approach would be to resample those. If you want to condition on $T$ (it makes sense in some cases but in others you wouldn't necessarily do it), you could draw enough times to do that. In any case, I'd do simulation first to check it behaves appropriately in these circumstances. I think your first suggestion should work as a kind of block bootstrap,  but again I'd simulate to check it works well at your sample size and your chosen block size

Comment: @Glen_b what would this look like if I were to sample interevent times? Would I sample until I have the same number of events and use the amount of time that took to estimate the rate? Additionally, what is the main reason method two would not work? Thank you very much!

Comment: The way I see it the "usual" bootstrap would sample the same number of events, but as I mentioned, if you want to condition on $T$ (particularly, if the protocol was "observe for $T$" rather than "observe for some period that happened to end up being $T$")  you could look at conditioning on observing it for $T$. Method 2 could likely be made to work but the dependence induced by the overlap in times would require some care, I think.

Comment: Okay, thank you, that helps a lot, I didn’t think of sampling the interarrival times. I don’t think I want to condition on $T$